# Problems with downloading data from a FTP website using python

Tags: python, ftp, urllib, ftplib

I am trying to download data from this FTP site "ftp://nais.ec.gc.ca"
Python 2.7
I have tryied ofther FTP like "ftp://test.rebex.net/" and ftp://speedtest.tele2.net and they come up with the same error

I have the password and username and I know they work.

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("ftp://nais.ec.gc.ca")
ftp.login("Username","password")
```

The error I get is below:

> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

I have also tried `urllib` function and it seems like it can login but i cant downloaded anything or access the correct directories.

Comment: I have seen that post but mine is a ftp:// which is what I think is messing it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like this:

> ftp = FTP("ftp://nais.ec.gc.ca")

But in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) you'll find:

> class ftplib.FTP(host='', ... 
>   ... When host is given, the method call connect(host) is made.

Thus, the first argument is a host name, not a URL. It shoud be just `nais.ec.gc.ca` not `ftp://nais.ec.gc.ca`

Comment: Thanks that was it.